# React-native sourcemaps not working using chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, react-native, source-maps

For some reason I cannot use sourcemaps to view my react-native project files in the chrome debugger. Chrome immediately logs out:

```
Failed to parse SourceMap: http://localhost:8081/index.ios.map?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=true
```

I don't know why this is happening, because my team members are able to use sourcemaps with the same react-native project.

I'm using the most up to date chrome: **Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)**

Not that it matters but: **react-native-cli: 1.0.0**

This shouldn't be the reason but here is my .babelrc:

```
{
  "passPerPreset": true,
  "presets": [
    {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-inline-environment-variables",
        "./plugins/babelRelayPlugin"
      ]
    },
    "react-native"
  ]
}
```

Could it be because we're using es6?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the fix was to remove the node_module and install again!

```
rm -rf node_modules/ && npm install
```